# How to create a view from a join with multiple duplicate column names?

Tags: oracle, join, view, alias

I have a few tables with this sort of format

```
myTable: id | Table1_id | Table2_id | Table3_id | value

Table1: id | text | ...

Table2: id | text | ...

Table3: id | text | ...
```

I want to create a view that replaces the ID's with the associated text. I can get that using 3 join statements like shown:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.id, table3.id, value
FROM myTable

INNER JOIN Table1
  ON Table1_id = Table1.id
INNER JOIN Table2
  ON Table2_id = Table2.id
INNER JOIN Table3
  ON Table3_id = Table3.id;
```

When I try to create a view using

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS (

SELECT table1.id, table2.id, table3.id, value
FROM myTable

   INNER JOIN Table1
     ON Table1_id = Table1.id  -- I tried as t1 but that doesn't work
   INNER JOIN Table2
     ON Table2_id = Table2.id
   INNER JOIN Table3
     ON Table3_id = Table3.id
);
```

I get an `ORA-00957: duplicate column name` error, which makes sense, they all have the same `id` column. How do I use an alias or something similar so I can create the view which has a format like this:

```
myTable: id | t1 | t2 | t3 | value
```

where `tn` is the column name that contains `tn.text`.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW myView AS ( SELECT table1.id AS t1id, table2.id AS t2id, table3.id AS t3id, value ...`

Comment: didn't see you post that as I was typing an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the alias goes up with the `SELECT` statement so the query would be:

```
CREATE VIEW myView as (

  SELECT table1.id as t1, table2.id as t2, table3.id as t3, value
  FROM myTable

  INNER JOIN Table1
    ON Table1_id = Table1.id
  INNER JOIN Table2
   ON Table2_id = Table2.id
  INNER JOIN Table3
   ON Table3_id = Table3.id

);
```